# altering onload event after body tag is printed, using jQuery .ready() in body of document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tabbed page I inherited that works through a number of queries and the results determine what tabs are printed.

I want to implement some logic in PHP that will cause one tab or another to be the tab with focus when page load is completed.

Is it good practice to add a call to jQuery's `.ready()` at the closing body tag of the document?

Any advice most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { });` can be put in script tags anywhere in your document. You can even have it occur multiple times.

Comment: Thnaks Jim.  Looks like it is working.  Want to add that as the answer?

Comment: Done! Also, added a shorthand for document ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(document).ready(function() { });` can be put in script tags anywhere in your document. You can even have it occur multiple times.

Also, a shorter form of the above is:

```
$(function() { });
```

Passing a function to the jQuery object adds the function to the document's ready event.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, it's recommended to put scripts at the bottom of the page, because otherwise they can hold up page rendering.  You can read more at the [Yahoo Best Practices guide](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: This refers to the actual downloading of the script, not processing functions or binding to events.  When a site is heavily built with JavaScript, most of the time you wouldn't want the page to finish loading before the .js files finish loading.

Comment: @Jim so anything going into `ready()` should be placed at the top then?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You *can* put it at the bottom (after all, it won't fire until the document is ready, which is after the HTML has been loaded).  My point is that your link refers to the actually HTTP `GET` request which loads the JavaScript file, not where to write JavaScript within the HTML tags, i.e. `<head>`, `<body>`, etc.  If you have blocking operations and you prefer closures-- `(function(){})();` to jQuery's ready event, then yes, they should probably go at the end of the document.